# Can't override Twitter Bootstrap btn class default font size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So here's the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-test" style="width:200px; white-space:normal;" id="up-arrow-div" >
   <div class="col-xs-2 arrow-up-div" style="font-size:30 !important">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up arrow-up" style="font-size:30 !important"></span> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
      Contribute more to support Last Minute Gear!
   </div>
</button>
```

I've tried in 2 different places to make the glyphicon size bigger but to no avail. Output still looks like this:

[image]
Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to specify the type of your unit, e.g. 30*px*

Comment: There are two instances where you have font-size:30 with no unit stated and no semicolon. Sometimes it's the small details that make you bang your head for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up arrow-up" style="font-size:30 !important"></span>`

to this:

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up arrow-up" style="font-size:40px; !important"></span>`

It appears you forgot to define a measurement type so I added px for you.

Let me know if that works

Comment: Any reason you changed 30 to 40px?

Comment: Nope, just like wanted to make sure 30px wasn't the default size. (bigger is better) :p

Answer (score 0):

You are using `style="font-size:30 !important"`

You should use instead `style="font-size:30px!important"`

Comment: You forgot to add a semicolon after px.

Comment: There is no need for a semicolon if this is the only style specified

Comment: I guess you're right. It's a good idea to get into the habit though.